# Couldn't connect to sqlite3 database with rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I installed sqlite3 gem with my rails application. I added sqlite3 to Gemfile and database.yml file and when I run **rake db:create**, **rake db:migrate** commands they are running fine but when I try to view it sqlite3 command prompt, i couldn't find my db. Please help me.

this is my database.yml file:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: emp_management
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

In sqlite command prompt:

```
raj@itadmin-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/Projects/empmanagement$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.8.2 2013-12-06 14:53:30
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .databases
seq  name             file                                                      
---  ---------------  ----------------------------------------------------------
0    main                                                                       
sqlite> .tables
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sqlite databases should be in the project's "db" folder (directory). It looks like that's at

```
/Desktop/Projects/empmanagement/db
```

So either

```
$ sqlite3 db/development.sqlite3
```

or from the empmanagement directory

```
$ cd db
$ sqlite3 development.sqlite3
```

The database might not exist if you haven't run the rails server yet, or if you haven't run any migrations yet.

Comment: Another option is to use the Rails `dbconsole` command: `$ rails dbconsole`. It will open the console of the DB referenced by the environment.

Comment: @Mike Sherrill 'Cat Recall':  it's very useful for a starter like me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need an additional gem in your gemfile

```
 gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.2.5', :require => 'sqlite3' `
```

You can use these commands to install the gem and support libraries

```
 sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev`
 sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby` 
 sudo apt-get update
```